# reference of ARIMA in python

Tags: python, statsmodels, arima

I used `statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA` in Python to develop an ARIMA model. Recently I am writing the methodology of ARIMA, but I can not find any reference on the page.

So here my question is where could I find the reference (or formula) used `statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA` in Python?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the documentation:

https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA.html

that shows the formula used:

> If exogenous variables are given, then the model that is fit is
>
> ```
>               ϕ(L)(y(t)−X(t)β)=θ(L)ϵ(t)
> ```
>
> where ϕ and θ are polynomials in the lag operator,
> L. This is the regression model with ARMA errors, or ARMAX model. This
> specification is used, whether or not the model is fit using
> conditional sum of square or maximum-likelihood, using the method
> argument in statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA.fit. Therefore, for now,
> css and mle refer to estimation methods only. This may change for the
> case of the css model in future versions.

If you click on 'source' you can see the source code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm still confused about this equation. Do you know what X(t)β represent in this formula?